# Обновление записи в базе

Tags: hibernate, java

не отрабатывает, где ошибка?

```
private static void setOnlineOn(Online online) {
    Session session = getSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        String sql = "UPDATE online SET shop = :shop" +
                " ,mpc = :mpc" +
                " ,volume = :volume" +
                " ,uptime = :uptime" +
                " ,date = :date" +
                " ,missing = :missing" +
                " ,base = :base" +
                " ,is_online = :is_online" +
                " WHERE name = :name";

        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);

        query.setParameter("shop",online.getShop());
        query.setParameter("mpc",online.getMpc());
        query.setParameter("volume",online.getVolume());
        query.setParameter("uptime",online.getUptime());
        query.setParameter("date",online.getDate());
        query.setParameter("missing",online.getMissing());
        query.setParameter("base",online.getBase());
        query.setParameter("is_online",online.isOnline());
        query.setParameter("name",online.getName());

        query.executeUpdate();
        transaction.commit();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы не пробовал exception выбросить, он бы и сказал где ошибка.

Comment: Мне кажется, или перед "WHERE" не хватает пробела ))

Comment: А где catch?

Comment: ура!!)) пробела перед WHERE не было  
сколько блин трудов и сил потратил, чтобы в hibernate update строки сделать, итог - всё руками набивал..

Comment: @hitman249 я не особо знаком с Java, но hibernate - это же вроде бы ORM. Неужели там нужно писать запросы вручную?

Comment: Hibernate как раз и предназначен для того чтобы работать с данными как с объектами.

Comment: рекомендую форум http://javatalks.ru [Hibernate Tutorial][1]


  [1]: http://javatalks.ru/topics/11004

Comment: >Hibernate как раз и предназначен для того чтобы работать с данными как с объектами

собственно, я о том и говорю - в чем необходимость писать запросы вручную, используя ORM? Да еще и столь простые запросы

Comment: потому, что бился с этой простой задачей почти неделю, и даже создавал тут топики, но НИКТО из местных не смог помочь. Ни строчки кода никто не показал, были только ссылки в мануалы без всяких объяснений, только в мануалах то как раз это то и не описывается.

Comment: Мануалов полно. На оф. Сайте куча примеров. Книг полно. 

P.s. Прежде чем чему-то учиться научитесь искать и извлекать информацию. Это очень важный навык.

Comment: @huffman, я все ваши ссылки внимательно разбирал и сам искал и методом тыка прорабатывал. Но информации именно по этому вопросу вообще нигде нет, будто за всю историю hibernate ни у кого не возникло задачи обновлять Уже добавленное.

Comment: Предлагаю модераторам удалить тему.  
Правильного ORM варианта ответа не было.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@hitman249](/users/5984/hitman249) я давал вам правильные ссылки. Вы просто плохо пониматете документацию и судя по исходному тексту в вашем вопросе пока еще очень плохо знаете java.

Я уже давал вам ссылку на форму http://javatalks.ru/ Так вот там все разжевано. Вот прямая ссылка. http://javatalks.ru/topics/11004?page=1#50044

Вот вам пример того, что вам нужно.

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
```

import ru.javatalks.faq.persistence.hibernate.bookstore.Book;
import ru.javatalks.faq.persistence.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil;

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setPageCount(520);
        book.setTitle("Tales of Round Table");
        session.save(book);//сохранили книгу, наш id сгенерировался и сразу заполнился
        book = (Book) session.get(Book.class, book.getId());
        book.setPageCount(430);
        session.save(book);
        session.delete(book);
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

P.S. перед тем как начать изучать Hibernate изучите java.

Comment: давайте не будем тут ссорится. Я всего-лишь хотел вам помочь.